# How do I fetch and render images from an api?

Tags: javascript

I have an api which consists of an object that contains an array of jpeg links nested inside them. I wanted to render each image into the HTML document however I get an error of

> index.js:19 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'forEach' of undefined
>       at addDogs (index.js:19)
>       at index.js:30

I'm assuming once we fetch the object using the link, we extract the array of jpeg links inside that object and do a forEach() method on it. However it seem's I'm wrong, could someone help me out please? My code is below, which includes the HTML document, JavaScript code and the actual api.

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Intro to AJAX Practice Tasks</title>
    <script src="src/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dog CEO</h1>

    <div id="dog-image-container">
      <!-- images here -->
    </div>

    <hr>
    <label for="select-breed">Filter Breeds That Start with:</label>
    <select id="breed-dropdown" name="select-breed">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
      <option value="d">d</option>
    </select>

    <ul id="dog-breeds">

    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
const imgUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4"
const dogsContainer = document.getElementById("dog-breeds")

function addDog(dog) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')

    tr.innerHTML = `<img src = ${dog.message} >`

    dogsContainer.append(tr)
}

function addDogs(dogs) {
    for (const key in dogs) {

        const dogImages = dogs[key]

        dogImages.message.forEach((dog) => addDog(dog))

    }
}

function getDogs() {
    return fetch(imgUrl)
            .then((response) => response.json())
}

getDogs()
.then((dogs) => addDogs(dogs))
```

API(JSON)

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": [
    "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/komondor/n02105505_4290.jpg",
    "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/schipperke/n02104365_8190.jpg",
    "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/entlebucher/n02108000_3306.jpg",
    "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/keeshond/n02112350_6861.jpg"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Your inline `<img>` element looks a little messy (no `<table>`, no `<td>`, no attribute quotes, no HTML encoding of the `src` attribute value). I'd go with `const img = document.createElement('img'); img.src = dog;`. I'd also create a `<td>` and append the image to that

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having a loop that's not really needed. Your `addDogs` function should look more like:

```
function addDogs(dogs) {
    dogs.message.forEach((dog) => addDog(dog))
}
```

Which basically translates to "get the message property of the `dogs` object and call addDog on each of its elements".

Also, at that point there's no need to access the .message property in addDog, since the dog parameter in that function will already be an element of the array. So that could become:

```
tr.innerHTML = `<img src="${dog}">`
```

(Notice that I added quotes around it, and that @Phil is right when he says that your HTML is quite messy).

Comment: OP's `appDog` function seems to expect an object with `message` property so there's still a little work to do, perhaps `.forEach(message => appDog({ message }))`

Comment: You're right, I didn't notice that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I noticed a bunch of other problems too (commented on question), nothing wrong with your answer though

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an error in your function `addDog`; essentially you are expecting it to be an object with a `message` field however it is just a string so to get it to work you might just need to fix the way you are using it, for example:

```js
function addDog(imgUrl) {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.innerHTML = `<img src = ${imgUrl} >`
    dogsContainer.append(tr)
}
```

This is beacuse your payload has an array of image urls but you seem to have assumed that they are objects.

EDIT:

Actually you seem to have a mistake in your `addDogs` function as well.
I'd recommend you merge them into something like:

```js
function addDogs(dogs) {
    dogs.message.forEach((img) => function(img){
        const tr = document.createElement('tr')
        tr.innerHTML = `<img src = ${img} >`
        dogsContainer.append(tr)
    }
}
```